# JUnit 5 and Spring Framework 3.2.x

Tags: spring, junit, junit5

Is it right, that JUnit 4.12 and junit-vintage-engine (from JUnit 5) can be used together with Spring Framework 3.2.x?
Is there a possibility to also use junit-jupiter-api and junit-jupiter-engine (both from JUnit 5)?

Answer (score 2):

> Is it right, that JUnit 4.12 and junit-vintage-engine (from JUnit 5) can be used together with Spring Framework 3.2.x?

Yes, that should work.

> Is there a possibility to also use junit-jupiter-api and junit-jupiter-engine (both from JUnit 5)?

There's no compatible `SpringExtension` for Spring 3.x. However, depending on your use case you could set up an `ApplicationContext` in a `@BeforeAll` method and shut it down in an `@AfterAll` method.